# Displaying ads in a foreach loop content

Tags: php, foreach

I have a foreach loop like this

```
    $sn_count = 1;
    $html = '';
    foreach($points as $point){
        $html .= "<div class=\"points\">"
            . "<div class=\"serial\">".$sn_count."</div>"
            . "<div class=\"pointsdesc\">"
            . $point['points_description']
            . "</div></div>";
        $sn_count++;
    }
    echo $html;
```

This code output is like this

1 
First point description

2
second point description

etc...

Now i want to display ads after every 2,4,6,... points. I mean in-between 2-3,4-5,6-7,... 
Can anyone help me with the code?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the [modulus](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

```
$sn_count = 1;
$html = '';
$display_ad_every = 3;
foreach($points as $point){
    $html .= "<div class=\"points\">"
        . "<div class=\"serial\">".$sn_count."</div>"
        . "<div class=\"pointsdesc\">"
        . $point['points_description']
        . "</div></div>";
    if($sn_count++ % $display_ad_every == 0)
    {
        // append ad code here
    }
}
echo $html;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
$sn_count = 1;
$html = '';
foreach($points as $point){
    $html .= "<div class=\"points\">"
        . "<div class=\"serial\">".$sn_count."</div>"
        . "<div class=\"pointsdesc\">"
        . $point['points_description']
        . "</div></div>";
    if($sn_count % 2 === 0){
        $html .= get_ad_code()
    }

    $sn_count++;
}
echo $html;
```